# JavaScript Regular Expressions to get all e-mails from a string

Tags: javascript, regex, email-validation

Given a string, how can I match all e-mails thar are inside "< >".

For example:

I can have `xxx@abc.com` and `<yyy@abc.com>` and I only want to match the `yyy@abc.com`.

Thanks!

Comment: would your string look like `xxx@abc.com <yyy@abc.com>` because that's different from what you said, I think. Also, regex is NOT the answer to everything. Emails are meant to be validated by sending an email to that address, not by guessing what's valid. There's lots of reasons for them to be not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be really thorough you could implement a regex from [RFC822, which describes valid email address formats](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/), however, you could save time and headache by doing something quick and simple like this:

```
var extractEmailAddress = function(s) {
  var r=/<?(\S+@[^\s>]+)>?/, m=(""+s).match(r);
  return (m) ? m[1] : undefined;
};
extractEmailAddress('xxx@abc.com'); // => "xxx@abc.com"
extractEmailAddress('<yyy@abc.com>'); // => "yyy@abc.com"
```

Of course, this function will be *very permissive* of strings that might conceivably even remotely look like an email address, so the regular expression "r" could be improved if quality is a concern.